# ssh: connect to host Connection timed out

Tags: centos, ssh, apache-httpd, sshd, tcp

I am able to ssh into the centos 7 machine and httpd works well. After certain hours I ssh **connection time out**. Also http and https connections show **ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT**
After rebooting the machine ssh works well.
Same issue has persistently happened many time.
What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but check your router settings. Mine has a "Systems Settings" page with a "Session Lifetime" setting that defaults to 600seconds. If you can find a similar setting on your router, change it to a larger number, and see if that helps.